# Вот такая задача на Golang, в тупике тк. только начал учится

Tags: golang

Вывод елочки
Что нужно сделать
Попробуем вывести елочку.
В первой строке необходимо вывести одну звездочку, во второй - на две больше, в третьей - еще на две больше и так до количества строк указанных пользователем.
Например, если пользователь введет 5 то вывод должен иметь вид:

```
 *
***
```

---

---

---

Comment: Нет, так тут нельзя, вы должны показать свои попытки. Если вы вообще не знаете язык, вы должны хотя бы что-то по нему сначала почитать, попытаться что-то сделать самостоятельно, а потом уже задавать вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func main() {
     lenTree := 5

     for i := 1; i <= lenTree; i++ {
        log.Print(strings.Repeat(" ", lenTree - i) + strings.Repeat("*", i) + strings.Repeat("*", i - 1))
     }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Cпасибо! очень помогло!